# Why did Aoi suddenly hesitate to suffocate Asuha in the last episode of Qualidea Code?

Tags: qualidea-code

Asuha and Aoi were fighting against each other and the latter one was about to win. Just when she was about to suffocate Asuha, Aoi had a short flashback (see picture) and then she loosened her arm which opened a chance for Asuha to turn the table around.

Did she do that simply because Aoi still had some lingering attachment to Asuha as a friend or comrade? And why did the flashback show Asuha alone (without her brother) after probably waking up from the deep sleep?

[image: flashback]